# A large number of api calls using flatMap in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am doing a bulk operation where I need to call GET and PUT APIs for 400 different values. I am using a for loop and flatMap to get the details of a specific record and then modifying the record and calling update for that record. The code is given below:

```
for(let i=0; i<400; i++) {
    const param1 = this.collectionArr[i].param1;
    this.myservice.api1(param1).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$), finalize(() => {
        //do something after both api calls are completed
    },
    flatMap((result1) => {
        //do some operation and create object x(this.objx)
        return this.myservice.api2(param1, this.objx);
    })).subscribe((result2) => {
        //do something based on result2 and this.objx
    })
}
```

Everything works fine with this code. However I have observed in Network tab of Chrome that the requests(api1/api2) made get stalled for some time(ranging from a few seconds to a few minutes) because of Chrome's limit of maximum 6 tcp connections to origin at a time. This results in a significant delay between get and update operation. If someone else does update operation in the meantime, the process gets failed. To avoid this I need to make sure that api2 call should not get stalled and should be called as soon as response got from api1. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: use ConcatMap for waiting api1 success, and after call api2

Comment: eventually you can use `mergeMap(project, N)` where `N` is a number of parallel inner Observables (HTTP requests in your case).